# Fragment upon fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, fragment, transparent

I want add fragment B upon to fragment A. How can I do it?

This is my first fragment:

[image]

This is my 2nd fragment on top of the 1st fragment with transparent:

[image]

How can I write it with code? Plas write codes with fragment, not with activity

Comment: What have you tried? Seems like you just need a transparent (or translucent) background on the second fragment.

Comment: I will make additions in the 2nd fragment. You just need to make it transparent for the beginning and put it on the 1st fragment

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can just simply add the second fragment(B) on top of existing fragment

```
supportFragmentManager
   .beginTransaction()
   .add(R.id.fragmentContainer, SecondFragment())
   .commit()
```

by default fragment B will transparent if no background is set, you can set it's background to some translucent color by adding following line in fragment's root container

```
android:background="#66FFFFFF"
```

color is in #AARRGGBB format, you can adjust the transparency by changing the `66` field